# nodejs Error: Parse Error at Socket.ondata

Tags: javascript, http, sockets, node.js

I have got some error when use http.request to make a client request(node v0.6.18, v0.6.3), the following code produces the error and I have some questions.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var data = '多情自古空余恨';
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Content-Length': 1 //ERROR
    });
    res.end(data);
}).listen(3000);

function request(options, callback) {
    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        var data = '';
        res.setEncoding = 'utf8';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('error', function(err) {
            callback(new Error('res error: ' + err));
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log('res on end');
            callback(null, data);
        });
    });
    req.on('socket', function(socket) {
        socket.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('socket on error');
            callback('socket error: ' + err);
            req.abort();
        });
    });
    req.end();
}

request({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    method: 'GET'
}, function(err, data) {
    console.log('result, err: ' + err + ', data: ' + data);
});
```

Outputs:

```
res on end
result, err: null, data: �
socket on error
result, err: socket error: Error: Parse Error, data: undefined
```

Here are my questions:

1. Why res's 'end' event happened earlier than socket's 'error' event?
2. If I do want to callback an error when "Parse Error at Socket.ondata" happens like the above code or in any other situation, how to callback once instead of twice as the above output(IF res's 'end' event really hanppened earlier than socket's 'error' event)?

I need your help! Thanks.

===============================

I found the same code outputs:

```
res on end
result, err: null, data: �
```

in node v0.6.6 and v0.6.11. Why?

Comment: Mind if I ask why this is important to you? I don't recall ever seeing an incorrect content-length header in the wild.

Comment: Why don't you fix the content-length header and then try it

Comment: @Nathan Friedly ,Esailija,  I don't know why the ERROR "Error: Parse Error
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1124:24)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:348:27)" happened actually (OF COURSE I want to know how this happen and process always stop suddenly  with this exception)and I found this is kind of way to reproduce it from google.

Answer (score 2):

Because there's a content-length header of 1, when the `request` receives exactly 1 octet of data, it assumes that's all there is and fires the `end` callback. After that, more data is received that the socket doesn't know what to do with, so it fires the error.

To work around this, you could perhaps wait a short period before firing the callback for success and track if it's been fired. For example:

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

    var data = '';
    res.setEncoding = 'utf8';
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('error', function(err) {
        if(!callback.called) { // check before firing the callback
          callback(new Error('res error: ' + err));
          callback.called = true; // set after firing the callback
        } // ..
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        process.nextTick(function() { // use setTimeout if nextTick is too short
          if(!callback.called) { //..
            console.log('res on end');
            callback(null, data);
            callback.called = true; // ..
          } // ..
        }); // ..
    });
});
req.on('socket', function(socket) {
    socket.on('error', function(err) {
        if(!callback.called) { // ..
          console.log('socket on error');
          callback('socket error: ' + err);
          callback.called = true; // ..
        } // ..
        req.abort();
    });
});
req.end();
```

(I tried to add comments after all of the new lines to make them stand out a little.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And do you know why the output  has different behaviors between node (0.6.18 or 0.6.3) and (0.6.6 and 0.6.11)?

Comment: I think it was probably a bug that got introduced and then fixed (socket should emit errors when it gets bad data).

Comment: I have post a issue here: [link](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3354) .Should I install listeners to the socket object?